# How to set a blocking read from serial-port which will break on SIGALRM?

Tags: c, serial-port

Hi I am (unsuccesfully) trying to set this thing up, but there are so many flags, that I am getting lost in it. What I need to do is -

- open a serial port with specified baudrate, parity and stopbits.
- Do multiple reads and writes in specified amount of time (in
  miliseconds).
- If the time expires, start it again (with different data...). If the 
  time does not expire, sleep for the rest of the remaining time.

This is what I have done so far:

seting the serial port like this:

```
int serial_set_attributes(int terminal_file_descriptor, int speed, short int databits, short int stopbit, short int parity, short int RTS)
{
        struct termios tty;

        memset (&tty, 0, sizeof(tty));

        if (tcgetattr (terminal_file_descriptor, &tty) == 0)
        {
                cfsetospeed (&tty, speed);
                cfsetispeed (&tty, speed);

                /* test */


                // disable IGNBRK for mismatched speed tests; otherwise receive break
                // as \000 chars
                tty.c_iflag &= ~IGNBRK;                             // ignore break signal
                tty.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY | ICRNL);     // shut off xon/xoff ctrl and mapping CR to NL on input.

                tty.c_oflag = 0;                                    // no remapping, no delays

                tty.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
                tty.c_cflag |= databits;
                tty.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);                    // ignore modem controls,
                tty.c_cflag &= ~(PARENB | PARODD);
                tty.c_cflag |= parity;
                tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
                //tty.c_cflag |= stopbit;
                if (RTS)
                        tty.c_cflag |= CRTSCTS;
                else
                        tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;

                tty.c_lflag = 0;            // no signaling chars, no echo,
                tty.c_cc[VMIN]  = 0;        // read doesn't block
                tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 10;       // 0.5 seconds read timeout

                if (tcsetattr (terminal_file_descriptor, TCSANOW, &tty) == 0)
                {
                        return 0;
                }
        }
        return -1;
}
```

setting the alarm like this:

```
static volatile int g_alarm_flag=0;
static void alarm_handler(int signum){
    printf("alarm\n"); //I know I should not do this, just for debug
    g_alarm_flag = 1;
}

int set_alarm(useconds_t interval){

    struct sigaction sa = {.sa_handler = alarm_handler};
    if (sigaction(SIGALRM, &sa, NULL) == -1){perror("Cant set up signal handling on alarm\n");exit(1);}
    g_alarm_flag = 0;
    struct itimerval it_val;
    it_val.it_value.tv_sec =     interval/1000000;
    it_val.it_value.tv_usec =    interval % 1000000;   
    it_val.it_interval = it_val.it_value; 
    if (setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &it_val, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("error calling setitimer()");
        exit(1);
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

and starting the program like this:

```
int output_fd = open(OUTPUT,O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
if (output_fd < 0){perror("Cant open a serial port");
//    exit(1);
}
set_alarm(60000);
serial_set_attributes(output_fd, BAUDRATE, CS8, 1, 0, 0);
printf("here63\n");
char a;
printf("%d\n",(int)read(output_fd,&a,1));
```

With this setup, the alarm doesn't interrupt the `read()` only the time in VTIME flag does.
I can't use `select()`, because I need to do multiple operations in desired time. The `read()` on the last line of the code returns 0 (when there is nothing on the line). My solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36871256/c-blocking-read-for-an-exact-amout-of-bytes-for-an-exact-amount-of-time) was kinda hated...
My system is Linux mint 64-bit, using gcc.

Comment: Time to strat learning something about [MultiThreading](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_multithreading.htm)

Comment: Well, one way is to `siglongjmp()` out, though `read()` should return if you didn't set `SA_RESTART` (which you did not). As an aside, do you have multiple threads by any chance?

Comment: Yeah, this bothers me a lot (the fact I have not set the SA_RESTART flag). I was thinking that maybe some settings in termios set it on? I do have multiple threads

Comment: If you have multiple threads, it's possible that the thread running `read()` isn't the one receiving the signal. Perhaps you should try using `pthread_sigmask()` to block the signal in other threads, only unblock it in your reader

Comment: So does that mean I can't have multiple alarms on multiple threads???

Comment: Not if they're all using the same signal, that would be confusing (as these are process wide signals, not thread specific. You could use `timer_create()` an co to get a thread specific signal. Also, you could maybe use something like libev or similar to handle both timeouts and async I/O and hide those details.